# stack per thread or per method call?

Tags: java, multithreading, stack

In following example how many stacks gets created ?

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String [] args){
Test test = new Test();
test.callMe();
}
public void callMe(){
System.out.println("Call Me");
callMe2();
}
public void callMe2(){
System.out.println("Call Me2");
}
}
```

if there are two thread accessing main method at the same time, how many stacks gets created ? Isn't stack shared between methods ?

Comment: Where are the "two treads" you are talking about?  `main` is usually a process entry point, and at the process entry point you're usually talking about one thread.

Comment: ok. got it. but if two threads access callMe() method simultaneously then ?

Answer (score 8):

Each thread has a stack, each method call uses a new area of that stack.  This means if a method calls itself, it will have a new set of local variables.

Comment: The "area of the stack" that a method call uses is called a "stack frame".

Answer (score 1):

> how many stacks gets created ? Isn't stack shared between methods ?

Just to clarify, stack is an implementation detail and are not *created* in Java. Also, methods are language level abstraction whereas the stack is part of your runtime. The correct answer to this question depends on a *lot* of things like OS, the machine architecture etc. and is *not* covered in the JLS.

Comment: That's all very well but how do you run a Java program without an implementation?

Comment: The JLS may not mention stacks, but the JVM spec DOES talk about stacks and stack frames, as does the Java class library (see http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StackTraceElement.html )

Comment: @Stephen: But similar to JVM threads, nowhere does it say that "JVM stacks" are explicitly mapped 1:1 to run-time stack. The stack which you speak of is a VM abstraction whereas the OP is talking about threads and stacks in a conventional sense here though I might be mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

If there was a new local variable frame for each method call then you would not need a stack. You could do it all with heap memory. In reality, for performance reasons all practical implementations will use a stack and have a one to one correspondence between stacks and threads.